# How to run a command after creating a container using yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have very limited experience with Docker, and having an issue, so I have the following yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    python:
        restart: always
        build: .path/to/docker/file
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
            - "8888:8888"
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./path/to/file/:/app:z
        entrypoint:
            - python
            - -u
            - /app/run.py

    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxyyzz
            MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
            MYSQL_USER: user_name
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxyyzz
        volumes:
            - ./Dump.sql:/db/Dump.sql:z
            - ./Dump_Test.sql:/db/Dump_Test.sql:z
            - ./big_fc.sql:/db/big_fc.sql:z
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

I need to run the following commands for the second container `db`:

```
echo '[mysqld]' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf 
echo 'sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

The point is that I want to run these commands just once as when you provide a docker file for the first container `python`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first advice is to build your own image with your own `Dockerfile`. In this case you will do it once and all the containers will have the same config.

`Dockerfile` should look like this:

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY create_config.sh /tmp/create_config.sh
CMD ["/tmp/create_config.sh"]
```

Create `create_config.sh` in the same dir as your `Dockerfile` and put your required commands there:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '[mysqld]' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf 
echo 'sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

Now you can use it in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Keep in mind, that `context` is the path to the dir where your new Dockerfile is.

Comment: I figured out a similar solution, and your answer is confirming I was going in the right direction. Thank you so much.